# How to install wordpress on laravel homestaed

Tags: php, wordpress, installation, vagrant, homestead

I want to have wordpress install on my local machine but I want to have it install on laravel homestead and I don't know how to go about it. My first thought was to search for the command on google and here to install it using something like

> require wordpress...

but I couldn't find anything relating to it and all I could find was something like

> Johnbloch.

Is there a way to have wordpress install on laravel homestead?

Comment: Sure there is. Just follow the instructions on how to install it on a server. First step: create a folder for it. Second step: download WP and install it into that folder. Third step: set up nginx for the new installation. the `serve` command works well, but don't forget to put it into the Homestead.yaml

Comment: you know there are plenty of boxed available, right? You can use one built for wordpress. https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search